# How to Fix Error in chol.defalt(cov): leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite?

Tags: r

I'm trying to put a gate on my scatter plot, but I'm running to the error: "Error in chol.default(cov) : the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite"
I don't know what it means and I'm having trouble finding resources to understand it.

Here's my code!

```
 meantBB<- c("BL1.H"=9, "BL3.H"=9)
cov <- matrix(c(7.5,7.9,9,10.5), ncol = 2, dimnames=list(c("BL1.H", "BL3.H"), c("BL1.H", "BL3.H")))

GateBB<- ellipsoidGate(.gate = cov,
                      mean = meantBB,
                      distance = 1,
                      filterId = "test gate")
ps_rose.0t <- ggcyto::ggcyto(InFCS_ta[rose.0], aes(x = `BL3.H`, y = `BL1.H`)) + 
  geom_hex(bins = 300) +
  theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "white"))+
  geom_gate(GateBB, col = "#CB0001", fill = "ffa401", alpha = 0.8, size = 1)
plot(ps_rose.0t, echo = FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would a covariance matrix be non-symmetric? (Read `?chol`. "Compute the Choleski factorization of a real *symmetric* positive-definite square matrix." ) Are you sure you don't have a typo in your definition of `cov`? When I change the third entry from 9 to 7.9 the error goes away.

```
cov <- matrix(c(7.5,7.9,7.9,10.5), ncol = 2, dimnames=list(c("BL1.H", "BL3.H"), c("BL1.H", "BL3.H")))
 
 chol(cov)
#----------------
         BL1.H    BL3.H
BL1.H 2.738613 2.884672
BL3.H 0.000000 1.476031
```

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating on the issue and pointing out the problem with my matrices values! I don't have any background with matrices, so I didn't realize the values in my matrix would be the issue.  After a quick google search on symmetric matrices, I think I understand why my matrix is non-symmetric and how I can fix it!

Comment: So I tested out other values and checked for symmetry, but I'm still getting the same error.  I'm not sure I fully understand the concept yet.  I tested the values: 6,8,8,9.  I think this is symmetric? But I'm not sure if I'm missing a concept there.

Comment: M is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive. Unfortunately your new matrix has a negative eigen value. `eigen(cov)` shows: $values -> 
[1] 15.6394103 -0.6394103 , so I continue thinking you are not telling us the "back story" for these (troubled) adventures in linear algebra.